# Winforms: Change background colour of an element depending on value of a variable

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, c++-cli

I have a small project here in visual studio 2022, a Winforms c++/CLR project.
It is a pretty simple project and form, but I have an issue with the following:

In the Winforms app I use a small panel to display the status of some input that I get.
I want to change the background colour of the panel depending on the status of that variable.
So for example if the variable is 0, the background colour should be red, if the value of the variable is 1, it should be green.

I can easily make this work, when this is coupled to a trigger event from the user, such as mouseclick, mousehover, ....
But how do I make this work dynamically during runtime, such that even while the variable changes during runtime, the backgroundcolour of the panel changes with it too, without the need of a user input event such as a mouseclick, ... ?

What kind of class need to be made in order to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example that shows how to bind the Property of a Control to the Property of a managed class object, implementing the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface, used to trigger value change notifications.

In the `ColorTrigger` class, when the value of an `int` Property is changed, this also changes the value returned by a Property of Type `Color` and triggers a [PropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged) notification.
This causes all Controls bound to the class object to read again the value of the Property specified in the binding:

```
somePanel->DataBindings->Add(
    "BackColor", trigger, "ColorValue", false, DataSourceUpdateMode::OnPropertyChanged
);
```

Here, [DataBindings.Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.printpreviewdialog.databindings) binds the `BackColor` Property of a Panel Control to the `ColorValue` Property of the `ColorTrigger` class.

```
#pragma once
#include "ColorTrigger.h"

public ref class SomeForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
// Initialize with default values
private: ColorTrigger^ trigger = gcnew ColorTrigger();

public: SomeForm(void) { 
    InitializeComponent(); 
    somePanel->DataBindings->Add("BackColor", trigger, "ColorValue", false, DataSourceUpdateMode::OnPropertyChanged);
}
```

Or pass different Colors to the Constructor of the `ColorTrigger` class:

```
// [...]
private: ColorTrigger^ trigger;

public: SomeForm(void) { 
    InitializeComponent(); 
    trigger = gcnew ColorTrigger(gcnew array<Color> { 
        Color::Magenta, Color::Cyan, Color::Orange 
    });
    somePanel->DataBindings->Add("BackColor", trigger, "ColorValue", false, DataSourceUpdateMode::OnPropertyChanged);
}
```

Now, when you assign a new value to the `Value` Property of the `ColorTrigger` class, the Color returned by the `ColorValue` Property changes accordingly and a notification is sent, causing the Binding to update and with it the Property of Controls that share the binding.

---

`ColorTrigger` managed class:

Note that this line in the Property setter:

```
colorIdx = Math::Max(Math::Min(value, colors->Length - 1), 0);
```

trims the `value` set in the range `(0, [ColorArray].Length - 1)`.
You may want to throw instead, if `value` is outside the bounds of the array.

```
#pragma once
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Drawing;

#define nameof(_propname) #_propname

public ref class ColorTrigger : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public:
    virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler^ PropertyChanged;

private:
    array<Color>^ colors;
    int colorIdx = 0;

public:
    ColorTrigger(void) {
        this->ColorTrigger::ColorTrigger(
            gcnew array<Color> {Color::Green, Color::Orange, Color::Red}
        );
    }
    ColorTrigger(array<Color>^ colorArr) {colors = colorArr;}

public : 
    property int Value {
        int get() { return colorIdx; }
        void set(int value) {
            if (value != colorIdx) {
                colorIdx = Math::Max(Math::Min(value, colors->Length - 1), 0);
                ColorValue = colors[colorIdx];
            }
        }
    }

    property Color ColorValue {
        Color get() { return colors[colorIdx]; }
        private : void set(Color value) {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ColorValue));
        }
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged(String^ prop) {
        PropertyChanged(this, gcnew PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi @Jimi, thanks very much for the detailed explanation. I am perplexed how much work it is in winforms to do such a simple task.
I have one question though: 
So I have a char array, and for example  the fifth element of that array determines the color of the panel. To which parameter of the class ColorTrigger do I need to connect this array element?

Comment: You just get the value at that index and set the `Value` Property of the class, at any point. You should mention what that value represents and how it should affect the Color. As of now, the `Value` Property of the `ColorTrigger` class accepts integers that are in the range `(0, [ColorArray].Length -1)`. If you have different values, you need to modify the setter of the `Value` Property, so you can map to an element of the Color array.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's clear. The value of the element in my array is a (hex) char, but from that char the third bit for example is the value for the colour.
So it's actually a bool that determines the colour,  for example 0 is green and 1 is red.

Comment: So, you have just 2 colors to set? Then you can just set `trigger->Value = ([Your Value] >> 2) & 1;`.  Or simply move the shift to the setter of the `Value` Property and just set the value you get from your array. --  In the current setup, with default Colors (Green, Orange and Red), you change the Color of the Panel to either Green or Orange. Modify the Color array as required.

Comment: Hmm, still not doing what it should:
In my main.cpp I use this code: 
ColorTrigger colortrigger;
colortrigger.Value = 2;

And it does not change to color when I change the value of the colortrigger.Value to 0 or 1 for example.

Comment: What is *my main.cpp*? Is that the file that contains the app's entry point (`void Main()`) and calls `Application.Run([Starting Form Instance])`? Did you declare a new `ColorTrigger` object there and setting its `Value` Property? If that's so, this doesn't do anything. You have to get the instance of the `ColorTrigger` object declared in `[SomeForm].h` that is used to bind the Panel's `BackColor` Property. So you could have something like `auto mainf = gcnew [NameSpace]::SomeForm(); auto trigger = mainf->trigger; //[...] Application::Run(mainf);`. You have to work with `ref` instances here.

Comment: In the sample code, you have `private: ColorTrigger^ trigger = gcnew ColorTrigger();`: you have to change `private` into `internal` or `public` if this object needs to be referenced somewhere else in the Project (using the reference of the Form class that contains the Panel). Consider that you have all `ref` (managed) classes here.

Comment: If you have code in the `.cpp` file that contains `Main()`, you should most probably move that code to a different class or `.cpp` file that your Forms can make use of -- Keep in mind that I have no idea what you're doing there or how your app is structured (e.g., you followed the C++ definition / declaration pattern or the C++/CLI implementation usually auto-generated by the WinForms templates; here, for example, the `ColorTrigger`'s header contains both the declaration and the definition of the class, etc.).